# Python 3 Trying to access json array keep getting key error

Tags: python, json

Im using python 3 and am trying to access some information from a json query. Currently I can access data within payments by looping through. I try to do the same to access order_status and it doesn't work.

Json:

```
___order details___
{
   "message_type_name": "OrderPlaced",
   "order": {
       "adcode": "",
       "adcode_id": 0,      
       "billing_address": {
           "address_line_1": "123 east street",
           "address_line_2": "apt one"          
       },
       "campaign_code": "",
       "channel": "Online",      
       "customer": {
           "adcode": "",
           "adcode_id": 0,
           "affiliate_id": 0,
           "alternate_phone_number": ""          
       },    
       "device": "None",
       "discount_total": 0.0,
       "discounted_shipping_total": 0.0,      
       "items": [
           {
               "admin_comments": "",
               "cost": 90.0,
               "created_at": "2018-12-04T17:14:55.1128646-06:00"               
           }
       ],
       "manufacturer_invoice_amount": null,
       "manufacturer_invoice_number": "",
       "manufacturer_invoice_paid": false,      
       "order_status": {
           "color": "#A4E065",
           "created_at": null,
           "email_template_id": null,
           "id": 6,
           "is_cancelled": false,
           "is_declined": false,
           "is_fully_refunded": false,
           "is_open": true,
           "is_partially_refunded": false,
           "is_quote_status": false,
           "is_shipped": false,
           "name": "Awaiting Payment",
           "updated_at": "2015-10-12T22:07:47.487-05:00"
       },
       "order_status_id": 6,
       "order_status_last_changed_at": "2018-12-04T17:14:55.0503538-06:00",
       "order_type": "Order",      
       "payments": [
           {
               "amount": 100.00,
               "approved_at": "",
               "authorization_code": ""
               "
           }
       ],
       "ppc_keyword": "",
       "previous_order_status_id": 6,      
       "shipments": [],
       "shipping_address": {        
           "comments": "",
           "company": "",
           "country": "United States"          
       },
       "shipping_total": 0.0,
       "source": "Google [organic]"      
   },
   "store_id": 1
}
```

I have a variable called data: data = json.loads(self.rfile.read( length ).decode('utf-8'))

I have another variable order_payments = data['payments']
I can loop through that and access is_declined

I want to have a variable called  order_status = data['order_status'], and then loop through that to access name. I get a key error on order_status = data['order_status']and I dont know why.

Comment: `payments` is a list of dictionaries. `order_status` is a dictionary. Unless you plan to iterate over the key:value pairs, looping doesn't make much sense.

Comment: not sure how else to access order_status->name though. Thats really all I want is to check that value.

Comment: That would just be a dictionary index: `data['order_status']['name']`. When I load your data I can do `data['order']['payments']` and `data['order']['order_status']` and both work.